# How do I forget adb debug permission

Tags: adb

I want to test some things in adb, but once I allowed adb debugging and the device remembers this permission all the time, how can I get the permission screen to come up again?

Here is how I can get that permission back:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgssO.png)

I tried a few `adb` commands with cmd, but I couldn't find exactly how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to developer options settings on your mobile. Then search for `Revoke USB debugging authorization`

Comment: I know it was revoked in this way, but since I gave this permission once, it does not ask me for this permission again and adb port detects it directly. Can I reset this permission to make some tests?

Comment: @İlkerİletişim Seyeds answer is doing exactly what you have asked for, please give it a try and then disconnect and reconnect the USB connection to the phone.

Comment: I wonder if this notification is not coming because I always allow

Comment: thanks i solved the problem
I deleted the files here
C:\Users\'NAME'\.android